# formDiv.dialog is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, bootstrap-4, modal-dialog

I'm trying to get add new popup form in .NET, but the console gives me an error:

> formDiv.dialog is not a function

```html
<a class="btn btn-default" style="margin-bottom: 10px" onclick="PopupForm('@Url.Action(" AddOrEdit ", "Product ")')">
  <i class="fa fa-plus"></i> 
  Add New
</a>
```

```js
var dataTable, Popup;

function PopupForm(url) {
  var formDiv = $('<div/>');
  $.get(url).done(function(response) {
    formDiv.html(response);

    Popup = formDiv.dialog({
      autoOpen: true,
      resizable: false,
      title: 'Fill Product Details',
      height: 500,
      width: 700,
      close: function() {
        Popup.dialog('destroy').remove();
      }

    });
  });
}
```

Comment: `dialog()` isn't a standard jQuery method. I'm assuming you're attempting to use the jQueryUI dialog method? If so you need to also include jqueryui.js in your page: https://learn.jquery.com/jquery-ui/getting-started/#basic-overview-using-jquery-ui-on-a-web-page

Comment: I've just noticed your 'Bootstrap' tag. If you're using the BS library then you should be using `modal()`, not `dialog()`: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#via-javascript

Comment: `<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.min.js"></script>` After including this , It's working perfect. Thank You.